# Pass control to another method in same controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   //SomeCode Here
}


public ActionResult CommingFromAnotherDomain(bool Result)
{
   if(Result)
   {
      //How to pass control to upper method?? 
   }
}
```

CommingFromAnotherDomain will execute first but after checking parameter in if condition. How can I pass control to upper method Index().

And I also want to check the below result in Index, so that I can eliminate some of work from that Index method.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You looking for something beyone `return RedirtToAction`?

Comment: You should handle this with routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   //SomeCode Here
}


public ActionResult CommingFromAnotherDomain(bool Result)
{
     if(Result)
     {
         return Index();
     }
     // some code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Global.asax you can provide the following route (or something close to it) in order to get to the Index Controller method.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "ComingFromAnotherDomain", // Route name
            "YourController/ComingFromAnotherDomain/{result}", 
            new { controller = "YourController", action = "Index", result = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: But he needs it just for `result = true`